# How to turn a displacement model in to something 3d printable

Tags: modifiers, displacement, stl

I have created a displacement object, applied a subdivision modifier and a displace modifier.
I am now at the end of my skill level. I want to turn this object into a STL for printing.[image]

---

Thanks Gordon. I completed the answer you gave but this is my workspace

[image]

Obviously I am way off?

Comment: Thanks for downvoting :/ But I thought I made it clear in my answer, it is made for _Displacement_ created by a modifier - because modifiers are the only things you mention in your question. But now it seems to me you made the displacement in the material of the object with nodes in the _Shader Editor_, that's completely different and maybe you should have mentioned it in the question. So I think you're better off with Crantisz' answer.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to do this as I know, is bake displacement map (plug it into emission and bake emission channel, EXR format recommended) and then use the resulted texture in displacement modifier, that can generate a "real" displacement that can be exported or applied.

Comment: Thanks for quick answer but there is a lot of information and I dont understand it all. Can you give me a bit more idiot proof detail for a newbie?

Comment: I can recommend some tutorials like this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=McALCOr39rY&ab_channel=CGCookie

Answer (score -1):

Do I understand it correctly that all geometry and displacement on this object is created through a *Subdivision Surface* modifier and a *Displacement* modifier?

In this case I would suggest to go into the *3D Viewport*, select the object, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and choose *Apply* > *Visual Geometry to Mesh*. This automatically applies both modifiers and keeps the resulting geometry.

Then export the object under *File* > *Export* > *Stl (.stl)* to get the print file.